# Проблема с загрузкой CSV файла и добавление записей в БД

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Всем доброго времени суток,есть таблица,в нее нужно загрузить файл .csv
Структура приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Метод в файле myPDO.php

```
public function uploadCSV($file,$db){
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO students (name,surname,age,city) VALUES (:name,:surname,:age,:city)");
        $data = array('name' => $line[0], 'surname' => $line[1], 'age' => $line[2], 'city' => $line[3]);
        $query->execute($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

Форма загрузки файла в views_table_students.php

```
<form method="post" action="index.php"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=file name="uploadfile">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning " value="Загрузить">
```

Ну и в index.php вызов метода uploadCSV

```
elseif(!empty($_FILES['uploadfile'])){
        $students = $db->AllStudents($db);
        $db->uploadCSV( $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'],$db);
```

Но при отправке файла возникает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее благодарю за ответ :)

Comment: код ошибки, что в логах? с таймлимитом падает мб?

Comment: `$students = $db->AllStudents($db);` - это для чего?